# How to change UITabBaritem title from the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uitabbaritem

So i have this tab bar item
[image: Tab bar item with default history title]

But i want to change the title to `Custom Title`

[image: Options to edit the tab bar item]

If i change the title in the section "Bar Item"
I cannot use the History system icon.

Is there a way to change the title and still keep the Default icon?

Comment: I don't think you can use a title and an iOS built-in app icon. If you want to use a title then you need to add your own icon.

Comment: Apple design at it's best, thanks for the reply